# Retrieving values from Json in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a table , which has a column with json Data

```
[
{"Name":"Territory","Value":"1000000002"},{"Name":"Village","Value":"Bahaibalpur"},
{"Name":"Activity Date","Value":"2016-6-15 5:30:0"},
{"Name":"Start Time","Value":"16:37"},
{"Name":"End Time","Value":"17:38"},
{"Name":"Duration","Value":"1hrs 1 mins"}
]
```

. I want to get Start time value and end time value inside function.

Comment: How is the values stored? In a varchar column?

Comment: Sql server 2016 has JSON support. prior to that it's only string manipulation, or converting the json to either xml or a normalized structure.

Comment: If you're using json data primarily, you may consider moving to NoSQL DB and having such operations easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
declare @t table(col varchar(1000))
insert into @t(col)
select  '[{"Name":"Territory","Value":"1000000002"},{"Name":"Village","Value":"Bahaibalpur"},
{"Name":"Activity Date","Value":"2016-6-15 5:30:0"},
{"Name":"Start Time","Value":"16:37"},
{"Name":"End Time","Value":"17:38"},
{"Name":"Duration","Value":"1hrs 1 mins"}]'

select 
substring(col,charindex('Start Time',col)+21,5)  as start_time,
substring(col,charindex('end Time',col)+19,5)  as end_time
from @t
```

Comment: its working but is their any way which i can get dynamically , without using substring. If value is "1.37" its breaking.

Comment: column name is BasicField , which contains json data

Answer (score 0):

You don't state which version of SQL you are using, 2016 has built in functionality(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx)

Otherwise, there is a cool article on parsing Json with TSQL that you can read [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/).

The other option is to use a CLR function.